# How to use LAContext's touchIDAuthenticationAllowableReuseDuration property?

Tags: ios, objective-c

in LAContext.h

/// @discussion This property can be set with a time interval in seconds. If the device was successfully unlocked by Touch ID within this time interval, then Touch ID authentication on this context will succeed automatically and the reply block will be called without prompting user for Touch ID.The default value is 0, meaning that no previous TouchID authentication can be reused.The maximum supported interval is 5 minutes and setting the value beyond 5 minutes does not increase the accepted interval.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval touchIDAuthenticationAllowableReuseDuration NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
```

But When I Use this property has no effect

## pragma mark - Life Cycle

-

```
 (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.transitioningDelegate = self;
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;

    self.context.touchIDAuthenticationAllowableReuseDuration = 5;

    [self authenticationWithtouchID];


    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(15 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self authenticationWithtouchID];
    });
}
```

after 15 second,Ther context's `TouchID` still authentication can be Available

whats wrong????

Answer (score 0):

The time interval is set on the seconds

Possibly the value you entered is a very short time duration.

Try to put an interval about 300 for 5 mins / 240 for 4 mins

```
self.context.touchIDAuthenticationAllowableReuseDuration = 240;
```